# ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Tags: object, join, merge, valueerror, int64

Hi I'm trying to perform a fuzzy matcher code but the following error appears:

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

this happens even the type of the columns I want to match are the same, the variables in question are `P009_01, P009_2, P009_03` on the left and `apellido1, apellido2, names` on the right dataframe.

```
df1.dtypes

P001                 int64
P002                 int64
P003                 int64
P017                object
P020_01            float64
WP109                int64
WP114                int64
WP115                int64
P009_01             object
P009_02             object
P009_03             object
tenure_security    float64
inv2                object
P086_01             object
inv7                object
inv11               object
P121               float64
c_ubigeo             int64
dtype: object
```

and the other one:

```
df2.dtypes

COD_PREDIO       object
AREA_HA         float64
DEPARTAMENTO     object
PREDIO           object
NUM_PREDIO        int64
ID_DIST           int64
ID_PROV           int64
P001              int64
P009_01          object
P009_02          object
P009_03          object
P002              int64
P003              int64
p_ubigeo          int64
ubigeo            int64
apellido1        object
apellido2        object
nombres          object
PETT_0            int64
dtype: object
```

the variables needed to match are from the same type so I don't see where the problem is, can anyone spot it?
and here's the code:

```
matched_results = fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(df1,
                                           df2,
                                           left_on,
                                           right_on,
                                           left_id_col = 'P003',
                                           right_id_col = 'ID_DIST')
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance!